# Data is not posting showing Internal server error

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, opencart

On click of buy now button product should add to cart button but it's not showing cart button even control is not going inside success function it is showing Internal server error when i refresh my page in cart button product is showing but it should work on click. How to resolve this?
Error in console showing like below:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

HTML code:

```
<button type="button" id="button-cart" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block buynow"><span class="bagImg mybtm"><i></i>Buy Now</span></button>
```

Jquery code:

```
$('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#product input[type=\'text\'], #product input[type=\'hidden\'], #product input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #product select, #product textarea'),
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#button-cart').button('loading');
    },
    complete: function() {
      $('#button-cart').button('reset');
    },
    success: function(json) {
      console.log(json);
      $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();
      $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

      if (json['error']) {
        if (json['error']['option']) {
          for (i in json['error']['option']) {
            var element = $('#input-option' + i.replace('_', '-'));

            if (element.parent().hasClass('input-group')) {
              $('.breadcrumb').after('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');
            } else {
              $('.breadcrumb').after('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');
            }
          }
        }

        if (json['error']['recurring']) {
          $('select[name=\'recurring_id\']').after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['recurring'] + '</div>');
        }

        // Highlight any found errors
        $('.text-danger').parent().addClass('has-error');
      }

      if (json['success']) {
        $('.breadcrumb').after('<div class="alert alert-success">' + json['success'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

        $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

        $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
      }
       $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
        window.location.href='checkout/checkout';
    },
     error: function(json){
        console.log(json);
    }
  });
});
```

Controller function:

```
public function add() {

        $this->load->language('checkout/cart');

        $json = array();

        if (isset($this->request->post['product_id'])) {
            $product_id = (int)$this->request->post['product_id'];
        } else {
            $product_id = 0;
        }

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);

        if ($product_info) {
            if (isset($this->request->post['quantity'])) {
                $quantity = (int)$this->request->post['quantity'];
            } else {
                $quantity = 1;
            }

            if (isset($this->request->post['option'])) {
                $option = array_filter($this->request->post['option']);
            } else {
                $option = array();
            }

            $product_options = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($this->request->post['product_id']);

            foreach ($product_options as $product_option) {
                if ($product_option['required'] && empty($option[$product_option['product_option_id']])) {
                    $json['error']['option'][$product_option['product_option_id']] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_required'), $product_option['name']);
                }
            }

            if (isset($this->request->post['recurring_id'])) {
                $recurring_id = $this->request->post['recurring_id'];
            } else {
                $recurring_id = 0;
            }

            $recurrings = $this->model_catalog_product->getProfiles($product_info['product_id']);

            if ($recurrings) {
                $recurring_ids = array();

                foreach ($recurrings as $recurring) {
                    $recurring_ids[] = $recurring['recurring_id'];
                }

                if (!in_array($recurring_id, $recurring_ids)) {
                    $json['error']['recurring'] = $this->language->get('error_recurring_required');
                }
            }

            if (!$json) {
                $this->cart->add($this->request->post['product_id'], $this->request->post['quantity'], $option, $recurring_id);

                $json['success'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_success'), $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $this->request->post['product_id']), $product_info['name'], $this->url->link('checkout/cart'));

                unset($this->session->data['shipping_method']);
                unset($this->session->data['shipping_methods']);
                unset($this->session->data['payment_method']);
                unset($this->session->data['payment_methods']);

                // Totals
                $this->load->model('extension/extension');

                $total_data = array();
                $total = 0;
                $taxes = $this->cart->getTaxes();

                // Display prices
                if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                    $sort_order = array();

                    $results = $this->model_extension_extension->getExtensions('total');

                    foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
                        $sort_order[$key] = $this->config->get($value['code'] . '_sort_order');
                    }

                    array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $results);

                    foreach ($results as $result) {
                        if ($this->config->get($result['code'] . '_status')) {
                            $this->load->model('total/' . $result['code']);

                            $this->{'model_total_' . $result['code']}->getTotal($total_data, $total, $taxes);
                        }
                    }

                    $sort_order = array();

                    foreach ($total_data as $key => $value) {
                        $sort_order[$key] = $value['sort_order'];
                    }

                    array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $total_data);
                }

                $json['total'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_items'), $this->cart->countProducts() + (isset($this->session->data['vouchers']) ? count($this->session->data['vouchers']) : 0), $this->currency->format($total));
            } else {
                $json['redirect'] = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $this->request->post['product_id']));
            }
        }

        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/845025/3676614

Comment: does you ajax request is calling?

Comment: @ricardo error message is 'Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "{"success":"Success: You have added <a href=\"http…pping cart<\/a>!","total":"4 item(s) - Rs 2,126"}", responseJSON: Object, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error"}'

Comment: @prakash ajax request is calling

Comment: are you getting these varaibles in your add() function ? `$this->request->post['product_id']; ` and other post variables?

Comment: @ricardo I have posted error message in controller it is showing nothing

Comment: @prakash Nothing is posting to add function. Control itself is not going inside success function.

Comment: because your post variables are not defined in the ajax call..

Comment: your data part should be like :
 `data: { 'productid' : $('#product input[type=\'text\'], 'othervariable' : value} ,`

Comment: This is opencart default code. They are posting like that only from product detailed page.

Answer (score -1):

Resolved It... There was nothing wrong with the script / code.. On server enabled 755 permission through out the  site and made 777 for Cache / Upload folders... That did the trick....

Thx all for the help and response... :)